# magento How can I set a url request like this? 'baseurl/frontname/index.php?/param'

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, actionmethod

I need to make an action method that will receive a parameter in the url, perform a search and return an array. Anyway, that's not the problem. My problem is that I want a url like 'baseurl/frontname/param'. I don't know how to do this. I've already seem a Magento site performimg same operation with a url like 'baseurl/frontname/index.php?/param'. It's good for me too.

Can someone help me to realize it?

Comment: Your keyword is _URL rewriting_.

Comment: Right. I fixed it. Any help?

Comment: I meant that this is they keyword you should do some __research__ on …